# Свет как синоним бомонда

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Бомонд, высшее дворянство называют еще высшим светом. Отсюда "светская беседа" и т.д. А почему, собственно, "свет"? И в каком тут значении: "мир" или "отсутствие тьмы"?

Answer (score 1):

Лексические значения многозначного слова всегда связаны по смыслу. Обычно бывает так, что у слова есть основное, или прямое значение, на основе которого появляются связанные с ним переносные значения сходства:

Исходное значение - свет-лучистая энергия, делающая видимым мир. От него -сам этот видимый мир -весь белый свет, общество людей.

Затем это значение сужается:весь белый свет делится на избранных - свет(знать) и толпу остальных-чернь.Избранность знати, аристократии подчёркивается эпитетами светлый (приближенный к божествам и их свету-пресветлый князь),блестящий (избранный при рождении, вокруг головы ореол света,почти святости-блестящая карьера),у них блестящая жизнь(блистать в свете), блестящие наряды,сверкающие дворцы, а для черни - беспросветная нищета, их жизнь - кромешный ад, они делают чёрную работу и т.д. Оформилось новое значение - избранный, высший, лучший.

Answer (score 1):

Индоевропейский и праславянский корень «свет» обозначает не только  светлое время суток», но и «мир, совокупность людей» (это же значение имеет французское слово «monde»).

Во Франции  светское (МИРСКОЕ) изначально противопоставлялось духовному, церковному, но в дальнейшем  приобрело особые черты поведения и мироощущения. (В России появление Высшего Света относится ко  второй половине XVIII века).

Светский человек был не просто богатым аристократом, он отличался от других людей естественностью и свободными манерами, отсутствием претенциозности и подражательности.  Можно было иметь незаурядный ум или быть талантливым художником или поэтом, но в общении с людьми показать себя несветским человеком, то есть  скованным,  мнительным, неестественным - другими словами, вульгарным.

Таким образом, с одной стороны, мы считаем светское общество "блестящим-светлым", но это вторичное значение. С большим основанием следует говорить об особом МИРЕ, то есть об обществе людей с определенными чертами жизни и поведения.

Comment: Вот как раз "особый мир"- это вторичное значение по отношению к избранности "блестяще-светлого " общества. И манеры у них "блестящие". А как же, их же воспитывали, учили манерам высшего общества.Только вот Ксюша Собчак не блестит манерами, хотя и относится к бомонду-"свету". Раньше было ещё одно значение слова "свет" - суетный мир, что-то среднее между свет как "мирское общество" (в отличие от духовенства, монашества)и свет как мир избранных, но лишённых духовности.Вот это больше нашему бомонду подходит, хотя сами они себя, конечно, избранными считают.

Comment: Каждое явление  в своем развитии проходит три этапа: оно появляется, достигает наивысшего развития и затем неизбежно стремится к концу. Так получилось, что Золотой век русской литературы совпал с периодом, когда достигла своего апогея и жизнь российского высшего света. Однако затем начался упадок: реформы 1861 года, появление разночинцев, развитие капитализма. Исчезала аристократия, и вместе с ней уходил в прошлое «Высший свет», превращался в пародию, а затем (в 1917 году) исчез совершенно.

Comment: В Европе  также происходили изменения: критерием светскости становились не личные качества людей, а роскошь, известность и умение стать известным.
Современный бомонд – это нечто иное, другой мир и другие законы поведения. Чтобы судить об этом обществе, надо иметь возможность видеть его изнутри.

Comment: Я в курсе, это я о Вашем протесте против первичности значения "свет"-избранные,блестяще-светлые по отношению к "свет"-особый мир с другими законами поведения, более высокими.Это появилось как раз потом, в 19 веке, а вот ранее высший свет манерами не отличался, Пётр1 вынужден был узаконить правила поведения для дворян.

Comment: Тогда он и не был высшим светом, а стал таковым только после получения дворянских вольностей, когда у СВОБОДНЫХ людей появилось понятие о чести и достоинстве. А Петр своеобразно воспитывал дворян. Так некоторые источники утверждают, что "больше всего ему нравилось спаивать до свинского состояния дам, а потом от души потешаться над ними".